# JBoss AS 7.1.1 and transactions

Tags: java, jboss, transactions, jboss7.x

I have created a [demo project on github](https://github.com/rsimoni/demo-tomee-hibernate) where I can try J2EE 6 features (the application has been create with the tomee archetype, but I have changed lots of things then).

When I launch the application with the [tomee maven plugin](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-maven-plugin.html) I can see application stores items and I can view them if I ask to list. When I launch the application with the [jboss-as maven plugin](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/) I can see insert SQL, but when I do a `select ...` no data is returned:

```
12:50:07,530 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: 
12:50:07,530 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)     call next value for hibernate_sequence
12:50:07,574 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: 
12:50:07,574 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)     /* insert icteam.demojee.domain.Book
12:50:07,574 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)         */ insert 
12:50:07,574 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)         into
12:50:07,574 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)             Book
12:50:07,574 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)             (title, id) 
12:50:07,575 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)         values
12:50:07,575 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)             (?, ?)
12:50:08,546 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: 
12:50:08,547 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)     /* select
12:50:08,547 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)         generatedAlias0 
12:50:08,547 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)     from
12:50:08,547 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)         Book as generatedAlias0 */ select
12:50:08,547 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)             book0_.id as id2_,
12:50:08,547 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)             book0_.title as title2_ 
12:50:08,548 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)         from
12:50:08,548 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)             Book book0_
```

I think it's a problem with transaction but I'm not sure I've done all the things correctly. What I have done is:

1. create a [JTA datasource](https://github.com/rsimoni/demo-tomee-hibernate/blob/master/src/deploy/jboss-as/demo-ds.xml) and deployed it on JBoss
2. added [transaction annotation](https://github.com/rsimoni/demo-tomee-hibernate/blob/master/src/main/java/icteam/demojee/infrastructure/domain/BookRepositoryJpa.java) (but I think they are not needed 'cause the bean is annotated as `@Stateless`)

Do you have any hint to give to me?

Thanks in advance

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I have solved adding on the [JSF backed bean](https://github.com/rsimoni/demo-tomee-hibernate/blob/master/src/main/java/icteam/demojee/infrastructure/ui/BookController.java) the annotation `@Stateful`.
I have find that it can run using any of these solutions:

1. annotate JSF backed bean with `@Stateful` and `@Model`
2. annotate JSF backed bean with `@Model` and `@SessionScoped`
3. annotate JSF backed bean with `@Stateless` and `@Dependent`